# Relación de muchos a muchos (N:N) con Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, api, sequelize.js

Actualmente estoy creando una API REST con Node.JS, MySQL y Express.
Hice la conexión con mi base de datos con Sequelize ORM y evidentemente lo estoy utilizando, a la hora de generar las relaciones de muchos a muchos, no he tenido la respuesta por parte de mi petición que desearía obtener.

relations.database.ts

```
import Position from "../models/position.model";
import Area from "../models/area.model";
import Competencie from "../models/competencie.model";

// Un área pertenece a varias competencias
// Una competencia pertenece a varias áreas
Area.belongsToMany(Competencie, { through: "AreasXCompetencies" });
Competencie.belongsToMany(Area, { through: "AreasXCompetencies" });
```

areaXCompetencie.model.ts

```
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import config from "../database/connection.database";

const AreaXCompetencie = config.define(
  "AreaXCompetencie",
  {
    areaId: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    competencieId: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "AreasXCompetencies",
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
AreaXCompetencie.removeAttribute("id");

export default AreaXCompetencie;
```

areaXCompetencie.controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

import AreaXCompetencie from "../models/areaXCompetencie.model";

const getAreasXCompetencies = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const areasXCompetencies = await AreaXCompetencie.findAll();

  try {
    res.status(200).json({
      code: 200,
      areasXCompetencies,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      code: 500,
      message: "The API generated some problems, talk to an administrator.",
    });
  }
};

// ...

export {
  getAreasXCompetencies,
  getAreaXCompetencie,
  postAreaXCompetencie,
  putAreaXCompetencie,
  deleteAreaXCompetencie,
};
```

Cuando hago una petición a la api, tengo el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No está mal, pero quisiera que también me trajera la data de los otros objetos que están relacionados con el id, algo parecido a esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar eagger loading, que consiste en que en el codigo findAll() agreges el {include: "valor que deseas agregar}.

`const getAreasXCompetencies = async (req: Request, res: Response) => { const areasXCompetencies = await AreaXCompetencie.findAll({include:"Nombre de la tabla});`

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que encontré para este problema es que cuando haces la consulta debes pasar un objeto como el siguiente:

```
const personaje = await Personaje.findOne({ 
     include: {
            model: Entretenimiento,
            through: {
              attributes: []
            }
} })
```

Ahora, cabe aclarar que tengo una relación N:M por lo que con sequelize creo la relación de esta manera:

```
Personaje.belongsToMany(Entretenimiento, { through: 'pelicula_personaje' });
Entretenimiento.belongsToMany(Personaje, { through: 'pelicula_personaje' });
```

Esto último claramente lo creo antes de realizar la consulta.